# Flush/drain stdout/stderr in Node.js process before exiting

Tags: node.js, stdout, stderr

Is there a fireproof way to guarantee that all the `stdout` and `stderr` in a Node.js process has made its way to the destination (in as much is possible) before allowing a Node.js process to completely terminate?

On some occasions I have consistently seen stdout and stderr fail to make it out of the node.js process before terminating.

What I am thinking is:

```
process.once('exit', function(){

   // use some synchronous call to flush or drain stdout and stderr

});
```

anyone found a surefire way to do this? Mostly I haven't seen this problem occur, but I am just looking for any possible way that I can add some extra insurance to this.